# Slight delay before image blurred

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm using `LBBlurredImage` https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage
with this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/55384/ios-7-best-practices-part-1, and was wondering why it takes a second when a `UITableViewCell` is supposed to blur (when swiping up immediately when the app opens to see the next tableview cell)?

**When I swipe up to go to the next table view cell, the background image takes a second to actually blur.**

***Swipe... hasn't blurred yet:***
[image]

***... then finally blurs after a second:***
[image]

Comment: Sorry about that! I assumed I was filtering by my tags when looking through questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was wondering why it takes a second when a UITableViewCell is supposed to blur

Because the blur you are using involves a calculation that takes some time to perform.

Comment: Should I use a different solution to blur it, or is any blur going to take that much time to perform essentially?

Comment: A faster blur will be faster. On iOS 8, UIBlurEffect takes no time at all. And GPUImage can be a very fast solution. But that isn't what you asked!

Comment: I see.  So the solution is basically to not have a lag is to not use `LBBlurredImage` and switch to `UIBlurEffect`?

Comment: It's a solution if it solves the problem for you. Try it and see.